# distinct complex embeddings of a Kleinian group, and Mostow-Prasad rigidity

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-topology, trace, low-dimensional-topology

I am reviewing some things I studied over a year ago about the arithmetic of hyperbolic $3$-manifolds, and hoping for some help getting the rust out.

Let $\Gamma$
be a torsion-free *Kleinian group*, i.e. a discrete subgroup of $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ with no elliptic elements.
Suppose further that $\Gamma$
has finite co-volume, i.e. the manifold $\mathcal{H}^3/\Gamma$
given by the Möbius action of $\Gamma$
on the hyperbolic upper half-space $\mathcal{H}^3$
has finite volume.
Mostow-Prasad rigidity tells us that if $\Gamma'\cong\Gamma$
is another finite-covolume torsion-free Kleinian group,
then there exists some $\delta\in\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{C})$
such that this isomorphism is realized by
$$\Gamma\rightarrow\Gamma', \quad \gamma\mapsto\delta\gamma\delta^{-1}.$$

The *trace field* of $\Gamma$
is defined as $\mathbb{Q}\big(\big\{\mathrm{tr}(\gamma)\mid\gamma\in\Gamma\big\}\big)$,
and I'll denote this by $K\Gamma$. Since the trace is invariant under conjugation, it is invariant of the isomorphism class of $\Gamma$. A theorem of Neumann-Reid tells us that the trace field is a concrete number field, i.e. a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ with a fixed embedding into $\mathbb{C}$.

Now suppose the trace field of $\Gamma$
has a complex embedding $\sigma$
in addition to the identity map and complex conjugation
(this forces $\Gamma$
to be non-arithmetic),
and define
$$\sigma(\Gamma):=
\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma(a) & \sigma(b)\\
\sigma(c) & \sigma(d)
\end{pmatrix}\;\middle|\;
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}\in\Gamma\right\}.$$
This seems to give
$\Gamma\cong\sigma(\Gamma)$
and $K\Gamma\neq K\sigma(\Gamma)$,
but that would contradict the previous paragraph.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that any embeddings besides the identity and complex conjugation are not discrete. Thus $\sigma(\Gamma)$ as in the question is not actually a Kleinian group, so the rigidity theorem does not apply to it.

Comment: Right..........